# WPF C# How can I filter a ObservableCollection or QueryableCollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf

WPF C# How can I filter a ObservableCollection or QueryableCollectionView?

I want to filter and list all categories which has the same duplicated Category Code.

Like code: Test123 consists of these categories. In other word, the categorycode should be unique.

I tried this with QueryableCollectionView:

```
var test = CategoryCollection.GroupBy(Category => Category.Code).Where(w => w.Count() > 1);
```

But it didn't work.

My code sample:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Category> GetCategory
    {
        get
        {
            this._getCategory = GetCategory();
            this._getCategory.GroupBy(category => category.Code).ToList().Where(w => w.Count() > 1); ;
            this._getCategory = new ObservableCollection<Category>(_getCategory);
            return this._getCategory.               
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._getCategory != value)
            {
                this._getCategory = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("GetCategory");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need an ICollectionView as shown here: http://www.wpftutorial.net/dataviews.html
You can then get away with using a List instead of an ObservableCollection if you wish.

Comment: Does changes etc to the collection or the data also apply to this collection?

Comment: If you were to use a List as the base property then I would say no, so in that case you can use an ObservableCollection as it would suit your needs. But whenever you change the filtering or something else you need to call .Refresh() on your ICollectionView

Comment: Hi, I'm not going to change the filter. I just want to list all the categories that is duplicated by checking if a code exist more than one time. I would like to use obseravblecollection for this, if it's possible to filter.

Comment: It sounds very much like you're trying to do a couple of things with this collection. Are you trying to keep a collection with unique categories? If so then in your logic to add items you need to check for duplicates or even use a different type of collection, a dictionary for example. Also view which categories are duplicate, for what reason? If you can give a more complete explanation we can help more.

Comment: Sorry for a bad description @Coops - What I want to do is show the data in a ListBox. By clicking on an item in the listBox, I should get the property code for this item autofilled in a textbox, which I may change code value. By changing the code value, I want the item the is in the collection to disappear from the list, as it no longer is a duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a code sample that works as you've described now, see below:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApplication.MainWindowView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="450" 
    Width="800">

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="CategoryListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CategoryCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=CategoryListBox, Path=SelectedItem.Code}" />
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace TestWpfApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindowView : Window
    {
        private readonly MainWindowViewModel _mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

        public MainWindowView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = _mainWindowViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace TestWpfApplication
{
    internal class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        private readonly List<Category> _categories;

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            _categories = new List<Category>
            {
                new Category {Code = 1, Description = "Blah"},
                new Category {Code = 1, Description = "Blah"},
                new Category {Code = 2, Description = "Pop"},
                new Category {Code = 3, Description = "No"},
                new Category {Code = 3, Description = "No"},
                new Category {Code = 4, Description = "Yes"}
            };

            HookUpCategoryEvents();

            CategoryCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_categories);
            CategoryCollection.Filter = OnlyShowIfMoreThanOne;
        }

        private bool OnlyShowIfMoreThanOne(object obj)
        {
             Category item = obj as Category;

             return _categories.Count(c => c.Code == item.Code) > 1;
        }

        public ICollectionView CategoryCollection { get; }

        private void HookUpCategoryEvents()
        {
            // If you add items or remove them at any point then you need to call this method
            // It removes the event so you don't get existing items being 'hooked up' double or more times

            foreach (var category in _categories)
            {
                category.CodeChanged -= CategoryOnCodeChanged;
                category.CodeChanged += CategoryOnCodeChanged;
            }
         }

        private void CategoryOnCodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CategoryCollection.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Category.cs

```
using System;

namespace TestWpfApplication
{
    public class Category
    {
        private int _code;
        private string _description;

        public event EventHandler CodeChanged;

        public int Code
        {
            get => _code;
            set
            {
                if (_code != value)
                {
                    _code = value;
                    OnCodeChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public string Description
        {
            get => _description;
            set => _description = value;
        }

        private void OnCodeChanged()
        {
            CodeChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

This displays a simple ListBox that is set to show the Description property of the Category class and a TextBox that shows the SelectedItem.Code of the ListBox.
In the ViewModel the ICollectionView has a filter applied to it so that it only shows items those codes appear more than once. An event is fired from the Category class upon setting the Code property (from the TextBox) which the MainWindowViewModel listens to and uses to call .Refresh() on the ICollectionView. There is no validation or other things that you'd want in production code but this should show you the basics of what you're wanting.

Comment: Your example is really nice, my only problem is that I use ObservableCollection and Queryablecollection for most of my stuff to hold my categories, and most of the application is done that way. Is it possible to apply a QueryCollectionView into Icollectionview with filter?

Comment: You can use ObservableCollection instead of List but as far as a QueryableCollectionView, this is something I've not heard of and looks from a quick Google to be a Telerik thing. Just give things a try and see what you come out with.

Comment: I've updated the code in the topic. Could you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use an ICollectionView instead of an ObservableCollection property, whatever you have in the View will bind to it.

Comment: Let's say if I have a ICollectionView instead of that ObservableCollection, how would the code be? I guess  I can just make do: private ICollectionView test = new ICollectionView(ObservableCollection)?

Comment: See my code listing, replace List<Category> for ObservableCollection<Category>...

Comment: I managed to make it work! What I'm wondering about is would this work for any property? Let's say if I want to list only those categories with the same name?

Comment: Nice one, that's great stuff @Fredrik Linger. Do some reading and playing around with the options available to you with an ICollectionView and you'll realise that you can do what you described and more...don't forget to upvote, you've taken a good bit of helping ;-)

Comment: I will try to do that! Thanks a lot, and of course I would update! :D You provided a very good example.

Answer (score 0):

var test = CategoryCollection.GroupBy(Category => Category.Code).toList().Where(w => w.Count() > 1);

Comment: Can I use a observable collection?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Category> listResult= yourObservableCollection.GroupBy(c => c.Code)
.Select(cl=>new Caegory
{
    Code=cl.First().Code;
    // other parameters of Category here
}).ToList().Where(w=>w.Count()>1);
ObservableCollection<Category> result=new ObservableCollection<Category>(listResult);
```

I don't know about QueryableCollectionView, but for ObservableCollection it works